# android SQLite database on SDcard, insert data and fetch result without using SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

following is the code which creates the DB on SDcard 
I am not using default SQLiteOpenHelper, the constructor is used here.. handler class will be used in Main class for instantiation.

```
public class DatabaseHandler {
     private static final String TAG     = "DatabaseHelper";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManagerDB";
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
    public SQLiteDatabase      database;
   File file_str      = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   String DATABASE_FILE_PATH = file_str.toString();

   public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
         try
            {
             Log.i(TAG, "donedddddd");
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH
                    + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null);
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                        + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
                database.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

            }
            finally
            {
           database.close();
            }

    }
    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone
// Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
         database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH
                    + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            return database;
    }

    private SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
          database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH
                    + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
            return database;
    }

    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
}
//////////
```

EDIT : Thank you **@Vigbyor** for your extensive help. I have realized after testing that this is the problematic code. When I try adding, It crashes. Any solution?

```
     // Adding new contact
       void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

**EDIT NUMBER 2:**
Finally I am able to insert. But Fetching the result is problem. this is method to get contact count, in DatabaseHandler class.

```
    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }
```

In MainClass if I try 
 `DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);`

`//insertion code here, which works//`

`db.getContactsCount(); //this line fails, even If I catch it in integer variable.`

Thanks.

**Edit Number 3**:
Finally after suggestion from **user2953017** and **vigbyor**, I was able to insert and fetch results. Following is the code modified:

```
    public int getContactsCount() {
        int count=0;
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
           count++;
         }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return count
        return count;
    }
```

and in MainClass,

```
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    Integer c;

        db.addContact(new Contact("Sandeep", "1234567"));
        db.addContact(new Contact("Pareek", "12345678"));

        Log.e(TAG, "ADD SUCCESS");   

    c= db.getContactsCount();
 //Toast just to make sure the number of records are returned.
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope it helps someone else too.
Thanks

Comment: @ketan app crashes.. but DB is created physically on SDcard

Comment: Please post logcat stacktrace - there are so many ways this code could crash.

Comment: Logcat is not working up for me for some strange reasons. :(

Comment: At least in the constructor catch block, don't ignore the exception but log it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the app is crashing because db value is null.
 try this code

```
void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
if (null != db) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
else 
Log.d("db is null");
}
```

or you can put the above code in try catch block

Edit :
you are Calling cursor.close()
which means  it Closes the Cursor, releasing all of its resources and making it completely invalid.
You can close the cursor once you have retrieved the values for that particular object inside your method.

Change your code to this:

```
public int getContactsCount() {
        int count;
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            count = cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();
         }

        // return count
        return count();
    }
```

Comment: This worked. Actually my insertion code worked too.
The problem is in fetching the result. I will EDIT the code.
Thanks

Comment: Thank You. Your code cleared me on my mistakes, i.e. closing the DB, Checking the cursor for null val and closing the cursor. I however did something as EDITed in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Why you are insreting data in catch block ?

```
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
            database.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);

        }
```

You should write these code in try block like below,

```
    try
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "donedddddd");
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_FILE_PATH
                + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null);
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        database.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }
    catch (SQLiteException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        database.close();
    }
```

Comment: Logcat is not responding to my log entries like `Log.i(TAG, "reporttt");` It just shows blank TAG when I add a Log filter.

Comment: filter the log cat with "AndroidRuntime" tag and post those messages.

Comment: still, nothing shows up. I have added an EDIT in main code. Plz have a look.

Comment: Finally I am able to insert data as well, but APP crashes when I try to fetch the result. I don't know whether it is because of any PK error(PK is NOT NULL so, it gets automatically created) or may be it has to do with schema of TABLE. I have confirmed viewing the DB that it exists and it has values inserted. 2nd EDIT is on  the way in the question itself.
Thankyou